# 2013 to 2016: Upgrade all DB's? Or just Content Databases?

Tags: 2013, 2016, upgrade, content-database

I am in the process of completing a Farm Upgrade from 2013 to 2016. I have the new 2016 Farm built and configured, and am ready to transfer the databases.

*I know that I don't need to move the following:* (Already created on new 2016 farm).
Sharepoint_Config,
Sharepoint_AdminContent.

*I know that I do need to move the following:*
WSS_Content_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
WSS_Content_MySites,
WSS_Logging,
Search_Service_Application,
Secure_Store.

*However: Should I also move the following?*

SbGatewayDatabase,
SbManagementDB,
SBMessageContainer01,
SocialDB,
ProfileDB,
WFInstanceManegment,
WFResourceManagement.

Comment: are you building the new Workflow Manager farm? or using the same farm?

Comment: Single/Same Farm. I see workflow manager components in my 2013 Farm, and we have lots of workflows running that need to transfer to the 2016 Farm.